# Is a congressman or senator legally obligated to consider the welfare of "long-term guests" or "frequent visitors" in their district?

Tags: united-states, congress, senate, house-of-representatives

The world is a complex place; if you visit a place a lot or live there temporarily, you can still be affected by its policies.  You might still want to complain about these policies if you don't like them.

Given that, **are American congressmen and senators required to listen to people who meet any of the following criterion despite not being subject to their vote?  Or does it vary by state or district?**

## Frequent Visitors

- American citizens who do not work in the same district (or even state) in which they live.  (E.g. living in New Jersey but working in Manhattan)
- American citizens who regularly visit other districts for reasons besides work.  (E.g. visiting a friend or lover in a neighboring district several times a week)
- American citizens who temporarily live in a different state or district.  (E.g. going to college or holding a summer internship in another district or state)

## Long-Term Guests

- Foreign citizens in the country on a visa.  (E.g. international students who may or may not continue to work in the US after graduation, and may hold summer internships at cities far from their school.)
- Illegal immigrants who continually reside in an area (as opposed to being migrant), possibly even with a family that was formed there.  Bit of a stretch, but why not.
- American citizens who are temporarily living abroad, e.g. for work.  (As far as I know, when abroad you're not within the jurisdiction of most US laws that your representative would vote on)

**EDIT:** Amended to focus on what is *expected* or *required* of a representative.

To simplify this, let's just consider the federal Congress; local or state legislatures would make things more complicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  They are not even required to consider the long term or short term or any welfare, preferences, desires, or needs of the people who live in their district.  The only voter accountability over their votes and bill sponsorship is that they could not be reelected or potentially be recalled if the law allows that in their state/district.

In fact they are not even required to participate in governance in anyway.  President Obama was notorious for voting present over 85% of the votes he attended while in the Illinois State Legislature and [65% of the votes in the US Senate in 2008](http://www.politifact.com/florida/statements/2015/oct/28/marco-rubio/when-attacked-missed-votes-marco-rubio-calls-out-b/).  And Marco Rubio took heat during the 2016 Primaries for a 50% Absenteeism rate in the Senate since he started his campaign for the Republican Nomination.